# Parse dictionary in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, dictionary

I'm working dictionary in my `AngularJS` project.

I want to show a list of `match` by `league`, and the name of the `country` above it, but something, the `league` doesn't content match.

If there's no match I'm not suppose to show the `country` name, but I don't find how to do it...

Here is my code : http://jsbin.com/hofayowamiha/3/edit

Any ideas?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a condition so the block is not rendered using ng-if. e.g.

```
ng-if="match.matchs.length != 0"
```

http://jsbin.com/vidihucihexo/1/edit